# Merge tags [screenshot] and [screen-capture]

Tags: discussion, retag-request, synonym-request

Both have similar wiki descriptions, and both have similar sets of questions.

Thirdly there is also [capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/capture), which again has the same description, but its questions are slightly different, some about video capture (despite the wiki description being the same as [screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screenshot)'s and [screen-capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screen-capture).

In short, [screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screenshot) and [screen-capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screen-capture) should be merged at the least.

An example from each of the three tags:

- [What is wrong with PrintWindow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241407/what-is-wrong-with-printwindow)
- [multiple screen capture with MSDN library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28261311/multiple-screen-capture-with-msdn-library)
- [General capturing with WM_PRINT and WM_PRINTCLIENT, supported on at least Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26060746/general-capturing-with-wm-print-and-wm-printclient-supported-on-at-least-window)

Comment: ... and capture should obviously be burninated, keeping in mind the proper tags.

Answer (score 14):

I decided to look through the questions in [screen-capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screen-capture) again, as it was pointed out that it can also include [video-capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/video-capture) of the screen.

- [screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screenshot) covers questions where a static image is being captured of the screen. This appears to be the same as [screen-record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screen-record), based on the tag wikis.
- [screencast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screencast) covers questions where videos are being taken of the screen.
- [screen-capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screen-capture) covers both [screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screenshot) and [screencast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screencast), plus more.

So because [screen-capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screen-capture) is actually very broad, and based on the questions it is also ambiguous, **I propose that we burninate it**. This means retagging questions as [screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screenshot), [screencast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screencast), or whatever other tag better fits the question.

*If someone wants to propose a list of low-hanging fruit that can be re-tagged, feel free to modify this to incorporate it.*

---

As far as [capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/capture), I think it should be burninated. It's pretty broad and ambiguous, and *might deserve it's own burnination request*.

- [42 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screenshot+capture) tagged [screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screenshot) [capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/capture) can have the [capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/capture) tag removed, as it does not help clarify the question.
- There are [75 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screen+capture) tagged [screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screen) [capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/capture) that are most likely for screenshots, and should be re-tagged as [screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screenshot). There are also [69 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/capture+image) tagged [image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/image) [capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/capture) that can also be re-tagged.
- There are [64 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/capture+regex) tagged [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) [capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/capture) which appear to be for regex capture groups. There are tags [capturing-group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/capturing-group) and [regex-group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex-group) for these, but for the most part it looks like regex capturing-related questions are safe without [capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/capture).
- There are [31 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webcam+capture) tagged [webcam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webcam) [capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/capture) that can have [capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/capture) removed. In almost all cases, the title or other tags make it clear what is going on.
- In the case of [audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/audio) [capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/capture), where there are [56 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/capture+audio), it looks like [microphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microphone) would work better instead.

This leaves [576 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/capture+-screen+-image+-webcam+-regex+-screenshot+-audio) which don't fit into the above categories.

Comment: [screen-capture] also means video which [screenshot] does not. So [screenshot] is a synonym of [screen-capture] or none at all.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I just looked through the [tag:screen-capture] questions and realized _it's really broad_ and includes [tag:screen-record], [tag:screen-capture], and [tag:screencast], with a mix of [tag:video-capture] to spice it up.

Answer (score 6):

Strongly disagree with the synonym either way.

[screen-capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screen-capture) can mean video capturing, realtime or recorded, while [screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screenshot) is a static recorded image.

It's more of a problem with [screen-capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screen-capture) tag [wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/screen-capture/info); it should be improved.

---

Edit: Okay, it's not as simple.

- There is a tag [screencast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screencast) for video capturing
- Wikipedia lists "screen capture" as a synonym of "screenshot".

I think this synonymization is ambiguous: quite a few of the questions in [screen-capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screen-capture) actually concern video capture.

Considering this, *maybe* it's better to burninate [screen-capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screen-capture) to disambiguate it.